# On mainnet-beta, signMetadata() returns a program error, whereas it works on devnet

Tags: web3js, solana, nft, solana-web3js, metaplex

The odd part is, the transactions both look completely successful. It's just that `signMetadata` *throws* an exception when using mainnet-beta.

Two txns for comparison, using identical code:

Mainnet-beta: https://solscan.io/tx/4zJ9qHRr3kDbhm7vMw4KmBmM4EZ8onx9ozbgKxrfw5wrvMTzaLfC1iDiYY1sQKbYKmYqVnDn4kntAwkwkG8US5Yy
Devnet: https://solscan.io/tx/3SZpHSEw3xhLKcBNiy6iPgkJvVnJNCCUjMfGHnmfvh7KWxd6zgnuDoQo1fbTCB4Uc6DqrsWfmDKAbyNR8g5wSCeK?cluster=devnet

The general shape of the code that is creating those txns:

```
const ret = await actions
    .mintNFT({
      connection,
      wallet,
      uri: `${apiHost}/metadata/${uuid}.json`,
      maxSupply: 0,
    })
    .then((res) => res);

  await sleep(20000);

  // Sign the txn
  const signTx = await actions.signMetadata({
    connection,
    wallet,
    editionMint: ret.mint,
    signer: undefined,
  });
```

Calling `mintNFT` then `signMetadata` after a 20 second delay, which I'd seen in some example doc or another.

The specific exception: `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x39`

Even when I look at the related NFT mint, everything appears correct. They show up in my wallet and look right on Solscan.

Mainnet-beta: https://solscan.io/token/KzFd3E5M1uZrYknzUmMnw7Z2xL11opQ24zmCBY9mPgD#txs
Devnet: https://solscan.io/token/7v3kbyjQeEyP4Ubw73kmfHcvwK5Jo63S4fqiHSFCS3Lt?cluster=devnet#txs

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.4",
    "bignumber.js": "^9",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-core": "^0.0.4",
    "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata": "^1.2.4",
    "@metaplex/js": "^4.11.2",
    "@pinata/sdk": "^1.1.23",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.12",
    "@types/react": "18.0.1",
    "@types/sharp": "^0.30.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^11.0.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "12.1.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.29.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preflight confirmation level of your connection may be set to `finalized`, which means that the transaction is simulated against the most recent finalized block, which is 32 slots ago.

If the cluster is going slowly, which mainnet-beta has been recently, with 732ms slots compared to 390ms slots in devnet, then it'll take longer to produce the 32 blocks.

That way, when you try to simulate your second transaction 20 seconds later, your first one hasn't landed in a finalized block yet, so the cluster rejects it.

To get around this, you can use a commitment level of `confirmed` on your `connection`, by creating it with:

```
const connection = new Connection('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com', 'confirmed');
```

More information about confirmation levels: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment

Comment: No sooner than I'd thought this was resolved than I'm seeing the same issue again, although this time only sometimes vs. every time. Could this be chalked up to mainnet network issues do you think?

Comment: Most likely yes